# Trouble setting up correct paths in deployed Github site. (using React)

Tags: reactjs

Using GitHub Pages I am setting up my recent shopping cart project to view as a live site. I've set everything up properly but only the main page loads. I have a nav bar in the header with two `a` links that redirect to the other pages: the first a Video Game page and the other a View Shopping Cart page. Neither of those two pages load and I'm getting 404 errors and I'm not finding any way to fix the issue. Please advice.

**package.json**

```
"homepage": "https://USERNAME.github.io/shopping-cart/",
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

**index.js**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouteSwitch />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**RouteSwitch.js**

```
const RouteSwitch = () => {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} /> // works
        <Route path="/videogame" element={<VideoGame />} /> // getting 404 error
        <Route path="/shoppingcart" element={<ShoppingCart />} /> // getting 404 error
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
};
```

**Header.js**

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <a className="active" href="/">
        Home
      </a>
      <a href="/videogame">Video Games</a>
      <a href="/shoppingcart">Shopping Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR ANYONE HAVING THE SAME ISSUE**

After some more searching I created a `Navbar.js` file with the following code.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="header">
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/videogame">Video Games</Link>
        <Link to="/shoppingcart">Shopping Carts</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I then updated my `RouteSwitch.js` file like this

```
const RouteSwitch = () => {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path="/videogame" element={<VideoGame />} />
        <Route path="/shoppingcart" element={<ShoppingCart />} />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
};

export default RouteSwitch;
```

No more 404 and all paths work perfectly.